# Calculate database performance on overload

Tags: database, performance, load, overloading

I don't know if this is the right place for this question, but here it comes:

I have a db function that I tested and can handle about 3000 requests/minute. The problem is that this calculation just gives me the optimal performance of the function (~18ms/request). How do I calculate the performance when the requests are twice, triple or n-times as that?

Answer (score 1):

try creating multiple threads or processes that all call the function as fast as they can. preferably use the same number of threads that would be used in a production environment.